# Cocoa : Add app to startup in sandbox using pyobjc

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pyobjc, appstore-sandbox

I am trying to give the user an option to start at login. However, the code below is working when I am running the app without sandbox but it is not working with sandbox enabled. I see this in the console: SFL(8490): AddNewItemWithProperties_rpc returned 5

```
def open_app_at_startup():
    app_path = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath()
    url = NSURL.alloc().initFileURLWithPath_(app_path)
    login_items = LSSharedFileListCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems, None)
    props = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithObject_forKey_(True, kLSSharedFileListItemHidden)
    v = LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL(login_items,
                                      kLSSharedFileListItemLast,
                                      None,
                                      None,
                                      url,
                                      props,
                                      None)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW5-SW1

The solution is that we need to use service Management framework instead of shared file list if we want to sandbox the app.